# proguard build nosuchmethoderror

Tags: android, build, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I'm building with proguard. I've explicitly told proguard to keep all classes that implement a certain interface.

```
-keep public class * implements com.me.app.views.Fooable
```

The interface has one method to implement: doSomething. But my app crashes when I build with proguard:

But I still get this error.

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: doSomething
```

How can I fix this so proguard wont ruin the build?

Answer (score 2):

You should keep the interface and its method:

```
-keep interface com.me.app.views.Fooable {
  void doSomething();
}
```

Otherwise, the method may be renamed or even removed.